# A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'. flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, cross-platform

> bool isChecked = false;

[image]

```dart
class _TasksTileState extends State<TasksTile> {   
 bool isChecked = false;   
 @override   
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print('$isChecked is the value of isChecked');
  return CheckboxListTile(
   title: Text('this is the Task 1.',style: TextStyle(
   decoration: isChecked? TextDecoration.lineThrough: null,
    ),),
   value: isChecked,
   onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
     print('$newValue is the value of newValue');
     isChecked = newValue;
    });
   },
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code snippet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

problem is `onChanged: (newValue)`, newValue is nullable, and your `isChecked` variable is not. you cannot assign nullable variable to non null. Either make isChecked nullable (`bool? isChecked = false`) or supply default value when assigning: `isChecked = newValue ?? false;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct way to use bool all you need is to add null operator

```
bool isChecked = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print('$isChecked is the value of isChecked');
        return CheckboxListTile(
          title: Text(
            'this is the Task 1.',
            style: TextStyle(
              decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null,
            ),
          ),
          value: isChecked,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              print('$newValue! is the value of newValue');
              isChecked = newValue!;
            });
          },
        );
      }
```